# hover.com + digitalocean: How to show url name instead of IP in browser address bar

Tags: heroku, dns, sinatra, vps

I suppose this might by a very amateury question:

I started learning something new by building a small website with ruby + sinatra. I signed up at digitalocean.com, set up my VPS and got everything up and running.

I also used hover.com to buy a domain which I point to my VPS. So far everything works fine, but in the browser the IP address of my VPS instead of the URL is shown, i.e. instead of

```
mydomain.com/articles
```

the browser shows

```
123.123.123.123/articles
```

The same is of course true if I run my site on e.g. Heroku, where the heroku-url instead of my own url is shown.

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best,

Tobi

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the answer to my question:

I followed the steps outlined in this support document and everything now seems to work!

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean

Enjoy the weekend!

Tobi

Comment: The link provided is dead